# AVR ATmega328 low fuse wrtiten and issue

Tags: arduino, avr, programming, fuses, avrdude

I am using an Arduino Uno as the hardware programmer together with avrdude as the software programmer for flashing an Atmega328.

I have noticed `PB0` was set to output the system clock with a logic analyzer. The currently running code was setting `PB0` as an input. Double checked with avrdude that the `CKOUT` bit in `lfuse` was programmed, so I have changed it like such:

`avrdude -P COM20 -b 19200 -c avrisp -p m328p -F -U lfuse:w:0xe2:m`

`-F` is there because this old avrdude that I am using does not know about `m328`. According to the datasheet the fuses are the same between the P and non-P versions of this MCU.

The low fuse has been verified by avrdude to be written fine, no more clock on `PB0` logic analyzer trace, all good. Except that I am no longer able to program the ATmega238. I am stuck at the dreaded `avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x000000`

According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf) `0xe2`(`0b11100010`) is:

```
CKDIV8 - unprogrammed
CKOUT - unprogrammed
SUT1 | SUT0 `10` - Slowly rising power (default) 
CKSEL3 | CKSEL2 | CKSEL1 | CKSEL0 `0010` - 8 MHz inner oscillator (default)
```

I wonder how I have managed screwing up this time and whether I can unscrew it somehow. Any clues ?

---

**fixed**

In short, no idea on what was wrong, but the previous lfuse changing just happened to coincide with the moment it has stopped working.

I have replaced the MCU. Still not working; observed a finicky MOSI line with the logic analyzer, messed around, eventually took out a 47 ohm resistor from the MOSI line and in the process galvanically separated another chip from the same MOSI line.

LE: I have put the 47 ohm resistor back in and it does not fail...

Comment: To unscrew it,  you need a High Voltage Programmer (12V) to erase all the fuses and start over.

Comment: @CrossRoads if only i had such a thing available, I would definitely use it.

Comment: Take a read here,  maybe you can put one together yourself. Not much is needed.  https://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12898

Comment: @CrossRoads Certainly a resource to bookmark! Thanks, but if I get to desolder the chip out of its PCB I'd rather drop a replacement in its place. Nothing important on this particular chip. I was more concerned with what I have done wrong than with the fix.

Comment: Fuses can be funny settings-wise. I only use the standard ones that the IDE works with. And sockets for the DIP parts.

Comment: I've made an HVSP for attiny chips, mostly as an exercise (although the 328p uses HVPP). The fuse command you sent would not brick the chip. Are you positive that is what you sent? if it was hfuse instead of lfuse, that would disable serial programming. Otherwise, the common way to screw it up is to change the timer settings. Other times, my programmer was just having a bad day...

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier change the timer settings? what do you mean ?

Comment: * Clock settings, I mean. This stuff: "CKSEL3 | CKSEL2 | CKSEL1 | CKSEL0 `0010` - 8 MHz inner oscillator (default)" determines if it's using internal vs external oscillator, the expected clock speed, how long to wait for Vcc to rise, etc. BTW, if you've never seen it, take a look at this App Note on Hardware design considerations: https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en591472